# Change accessibility setting on Mac for command line program

Tags: macos, command-line, accessibility, gatekeeper

I have built a simple command line program with Xcode, and I would like to access the NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents method.
It seems like the program must be trusted for this to work.

```
self.monitor = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: NSEventMask.mouseMoved, handler: { e in
    print(e)
})
```

How can I add a command line program to the list of trusted applications?

Answer (score 1):

> you have to export your app via Product > Archive > Export... > Export
>   as a Mac Application, then move the app to wherever you want it (i.e.,
>   your Applications folder). Then, you'll be able to find the app in
>   Security & Privacy to give it accessibility permissions

Credit to: [vincefior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1976584/)
In a comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496336/addglobalmonitorforeventsmatchingmask-not-working) stackoverflow question:

Comment: Not Working on Sierra! the tool is shown grayed ..